# How could I make a series of joins work with max value when aggregates do not work in them?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking only to get classification ids which are between the valid year range in classification. I'm using left joins because **NULLs** should be permitted.

---

I have tables:

```
CREATE TABLE classifications (
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [classification_code] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [valid_from] [int] NULL,
    [valid_to] [int] NULL
--Rest of constraints...
)

insert into classifications (classification_code, description, valid_from, valid_to)
values ('05012','Classification Number 1',2007,2012),
('05012','Classification Number 1',2013,2016),
('05012','Classification Number 1',2017,2020).
('12043','Classification Number 2',2007,2010),
('12043','Classification Number 2',2011,2020),
('12345','Classification Number 3',2013,2015),
('12345','Classification Number 3',2016,2020),
('54321','Classification Number 4',2007,2009),
('54321','Classification Number 4',2010,2013),
('54321','Classification Number 4',2014,2020)


CREATE TABLE comm_info_a (
     [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [comm_code] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, /*should be unique*/
     [classification_code] [nchar](6) NULL,
     [thing] [nchar](6) NULL
--Rest of constraints...
)

insert into comm_info_a (comm_code, classification_code)
values ('0100100000','54321'),
('8090010000','05012'),
('5002310010','12043'),
('0987654321','54321')


CREATE TABLE comm_info_b (
     [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [comm_code] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, /*should be unique*/ 
     [classification_code] [nchar](6) NULL
--Rest of constraints...
)

insert into comm_info_b (comm_code, classification_code)
values ('0100100000','12043'),
('8090010000','00000'),
('5002310010','05012'),
('1234567890','12345')


CREATE TABLE transactions (
     [comm_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
     [year] [varchar](255) NULL
--Rest of constraints...
)

insert into transactions (comm_code, year) values 
('0100100000', 2013),
('0100100000', 2015),
('0100100000', 2017),
('8090010000', 2009),
('8090010000', 2010),
('8090010000', 2011),
('8090010000', 2015),
('8090010000', 2017),
('8090010000', 2018),
('5002310010', 2008),
('5002310010', 2014),
```

---

And finally:

```
CREATE TABLE comm (
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [comm_code] [varchar](20) NULL, /*should be unique*/
    [fk_classification_id_a] [bigint] NULL,
    [fk_classification_id_b] [bigint] NULL
--Rest of constraints...
)
```

---

I am working on a query to insert comms from transactions, and comms should have unique `comm_code`

The query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO comm
(comm_code,
fk_classification_id_a,
fk_classification_id_b)
SELECT comm_code,
ca.id,
cb.id,
MAX(year)
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN comm_info_a mia ON mia.comm_code=t.comm_code
LEFT JOIN comm_info_b mib ON mib.comm_code=t.comm_code
--these next two joins obviously do not work so I'm looking for something like it. Treat them as 'pseudo-code'
LEFT JOIN classifications ca ON ca.classification_code=mia.classification_code AND
MAX(t.year) BETWEEN ca.valid_from AND ca.valid_to
LEFT JOIN classifications cb ON cb.classification_code=mib.classification_code AND
MAX(t.year) BETWEEN cb.valid_from AND cb.valid_to
-- end of the two joins
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT DISTINCT comm_code FROM comm)
GROUP BY
t.comm_code
t.classification_code
```

---

So in the end I'm looking to get something like this as a result:

```
comm_code  | fk_classification_id_a | fk_classification_id_b
-----------|------------------------|-----------------------
0100100000 | 5                      | 10
8090010000 | 3                      | NULL
5002310010 | 5                      | 2
```

Please note that the comm_code is unique in this table!! Therefore: i want the comms on the newest transactions (thus the aggegate max year), and they should have the ids of the classification that the transaction year is in.

The real query is much more complex and longer but this pretty much covers all bases. Take a look into what is commented. I understand that it should be doable with a sub query of some sort, and I've tried, but so far I haven't found a way to pass aggregates to subqueries.

How could I tackle this problem?

Comment: Too many tables ... can you post a minimal sample of your problem?

Comment: I'll try in a bit but as of now this is as simple as I could present it. The whole thing has a lot more tables and joins, so I only included the ones that I believed are relevant to what I want as a result. I tried to make it as friendly to sql fiddle as possible.

Comment: Remove the definitions, or at least the insert statements, and instead include a demo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer uses a common table expression to calculate the maximum year per comm_code and to exclude the comm_codes not wanted in the final result. After that the joins to the classification tables are straight forward as we have the `comm_max_year` value on each row to use in the joins.

> ```
> with transCTE as (
>       select
>              t.*
>            , max(t.year) over(partition by comm_code) comm_max_year
>       from transactions t
>       left join comm on t.comm_code = comm.comm_code -- this table not in sample given
>       where comm.comm_code IS NULL -- use instead of NOT EXISTS
>      )
> SELECT DISTINCT
>       t.comm_code
>     , ca.id  as fk_classification_id_a
>     , cb.id  as fk_classification_id_b
>     , t.comm_max_year
> FROM transCTE t
> LEFT JOIN comm_info_a mia ON mia.comm_code = t.comm_code
> LEFT JOIN classifications ca ON mia.classification_code = ca.classification_code
>       AND t.comm_max_year BETWEEN ca.valid_from AND ca.valid_to
> LEFT JOIN comm_info_b mib ON mib.comm_code = t.comm_code
> LEFT JOIN classifications cb ON mib.classification_code = cb.classification_code
>       AND t.comm_max_year BETWEEN cb.valid_from AND cb.valid_to
> ORDER BY 
>       t.comm_code
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> comm_code  | fk_classification_id_a | fk_classification_id_b | comm_max_year
> :--------- | :--------------------- | :--------------------- | :------------
> 0100100000 | 10                     | 5                      | 2017         
> 5002310010 | 5                      | 2                      | 2014         
> 8090010000 | 3                      | null                   | 2018
> ```

*Demo at dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2da0a9ce7077db56eed88333146e8536)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE transactions (
>      [comm_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
>      [year] [varchar](255) NULL
> --Rest of constraints...
> )
>
> insert into transactions (comm_code, year) values 
> ('0100100000', 2013),
> ('0100100000', 2015),
> ('0100100000', 2017),
> ('8090010000', 2009),
> ('8090010000', 2010),
> ('8090010000', 2011),
> ('8090010000', 2015),
> ('8090010000', 2017),
> ('8090010000', 2018),
> ('5002310010', 2008),
> ('5002310010', 2014)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 11 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE classifications (
>     [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>     [classification_code] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
>     [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
>     [valid_from] [int] NULL,
>     [valid_to] [int] NULL
> --Rest of constraints...
> )
>
> insert into classifications (classification_code, description, valid_from, valid_to)
> values ('05012','Classification Number 1',2007,2012),
> ('05012','Classification Number 1',2013,2016),
> ('05012','Classification Number 1',2017,2020),
> ('12043','Classification Number 2',2007,2010),
> ('12043','Classification Number 2',2011,2020),
> ('12345','Classification Number 3',2013,2015),
> ('12345','Classification Number 3',2016,2020),
> ('54321','Classification Number 4',2007,2009),
> ('54321','Classification Number 4',2010,2013),
> ('54321','Classification Number 4',2014,2020)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE comm_info_a (
>      [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>      [comm_code] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, /*should be unique*/
>      [classification_code] [nchar](6) NULL,
>      [thing] [nchar](6) NULL
> --Rest of constraints...
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into comm_info_a (comm_code, classification_code)
> values ('0100100000','54321'),
> ('8090010000','05012'),
> ('5002310010','12043'),
> ('0987654321','54321')
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE comm_info_b (
>      [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>      [comm_code] [nchar](10) NOT NULL, /*should be unique*/ 
>      [classification_code] [nchar](6) NULL
> --Rest of constraints...
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into comm_info_b (comm_code, classification_code)
> values ('0100100000','12043'),
> ('8090010000','00000'),
> ('5002310010','05012'),
> ('1234567890','12345');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

Comment: sadly this is not what i'm looking for. the comm table should have a unique comm_code, which is why I'm using group bys in the first place. The comm should be taken from the 'newest' transaction, hence then MAX() aggregate.

Comment: I revised my answer. Thanks for the clarification.